# how to add trailing or leading zero to `0.1201` or `01.00` total 7 numbers in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to add trailing or leading zero to `0.1201` or `1.00` total 7 numbers in Postgresql?

supposed I have data of below, and we have to store numbers in a varchar column(and this is not a broken database design, we also have some values of 02.34x924 in this column, could you please tell me how to save them to numeric or double)

```
numbers
0.1201
 1.00 
26.25
02.34x924
```

I expected output is, on the left of decimal point two numbers, and on the right of decimal point are four numbers, including decimal point total 7 numbers

```
numbers
00.1201
01.0000 
26.2500
02.34x924
```

I can use below SQL to let 26.25 equal to 26.2500, but I can't deal with `0.1201 1.00`

```
select 
case when length(numbers) < 7 then rpad(numbers, 7, '0') else numbers end numbersnew
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split the value into two parts then pad each part individually.

```
select concat(lpad(p1, 2, '0'), 
              '.', p2, 
              rpad('0', 4 - length(p2), '0'))
from (
  select trim(split_part(numbers, '.', 1)) as p1, 
         trim(split_part(numbers, '.', 2)) as p2 
  from my_table
) t
```

The derived table is mainly there to avoid repeating the expression to get each part.

I would put that into a function to make your queries easier to read:

```
create function format_my_string(p_input text)
  returns text
as
$$
select concat(lpad(p1, 2, '0'), 
              '.', p2, 
              rpad('0', 4 - length(p2), '0'))
from (
  select trim(split_part(p_input, '.', 1)) as p1, 
         trim(split_part(p_input, '.', 2)) as p2 
) t;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select format_my_string(numbers)
from my_table
```